# How can I make an installation for my Windows Mobile or Windows CE program using my PC?

Tags: windows-mobile, installation, windows-ce

How can I make an installation for my Windows Mobile or Windows CE program using my PC?

Comment: You want to try explaining the problem a little better? You mean make a CAB file?

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
File > New > Project
```

Then:

```
Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Smart Device CAB Project
```